# get the default email from the user on a Linux box

Tags: c, linux, email

Is there any way to programmatically get the current user's email address?
I know the email is usually user@hostname but is there any I can get the email? 
I know how to get the username and the hostname so I can build it myself, but I want to be sure that I get the email address even when the email is not user@hostname.

Code in C is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Even if you went to all of the effort to parse the various configuration files to determine the email address(es) it's *very* likely the user will have multiple accounts and you'd have to prompt them to choose.  A better question might be how to *validate* the email address chosen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such standard mapping of user account to email address - at least not for ordinary /etc/passwd derived accounts. Consider that a user might not even have an email address.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody's mentioned the [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) fields in the /etc/passwd file.

You'll notice that the fifth field in your entry in /etc/passwd is either blank, or a comma-separated list the first element of which is your full name. Originally in Bell Labs (before the days of email) the GECOS fields were:

1. User's full name (or application name, if the account is for a
   program)
2. Building and room number or contact person
3. Office telephone
   number
4. Any other contact information (pager number, fax, etc.)

Some Linux distributions store the user's default email address in the 4th GECOS field, and if your system doesn't do this by default, you can set it up yourself. Ordinary users without superuser privilege can edit their GECOS fields using the command line command [*chfn*](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/chfn.htm). To access this field, you can then do

```
grep ${USER}: /etc/passwd | awk -F\: '{print $5}' | awk -F\, '{print $4}'
```

or whatever floats your boat in your language of choice (No, I am *NOT* going to write C. This is the twenty-first century!).

Comment: I would just suggest changing "grep ${USER} /etc/passwd" for "getent passed ${USER}", to allow finding users in other NSS sources, such as LDAP.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard mapping of user accounts to RFC822 (i.e. user@domain) email addresses.  Generally, a default setup of typical mail transfer agents will accept local mail to addresses without a domain and deliver it to the user account of the same name.  But even that can't be relied on, as you may not even have an MTA.

Comment: There's no way to **derive** it from the software configuration on a local box, no.  Obviously there's a way to get it: ask someone (the user, an administrator) what the email configuration for users on the box is.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968376/1714951) and given I don't have enough reputation to make a comment on it, *GECOS* stands for *General Comprehensive Operating System* aka *General Electric Comprehensive Operating Supervisor* and the most portable way I found to get the user GECOS field (As it might not be defined in your `/etc/passwd` file directly depending on your system's configuration) is the following:

`getent passwd <USERNAME> | awk -F ':' '{print $5}'`

Answer (score 3):

The UNIX way of doing this is to send email through the local mail-transfer-agent - simply invoking `/usr/bin/mail` is enough.  The system administrator is responsible for configuring the local MTA to make sure email works properly.

- If you want to *send* email to the local user, just send it to their username - if they read their email somewhere other than locally, the MTA should be configured to forward it to them.
- If you just want to use the right "from" email address when sending email on behalf of a local user, so they get replies in the right place - again, just use their username.  The MTA should be configured to do the right translation.

This way of doing things is good, because it means that this configuration only has to be done in one place (the MTA), rather than having to manually configure every single application on the box that sends or recieves email.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the user is stored. In a simple passwd file there's no email address, only a username. But you can have additional information with other authentication method like LDAP or SQL.

Comment: Like I said, it depends. There's no default email "option" in a unix account. uri@hostname only means "the user uri at the address hostname", litterally.

Comment: But, let's say you are authenticating against a LDAP server (OpenLDAP, Active Directory, etc), you have an email option that you can retrieve with the ldap client library.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user for their email.  If you have no guarantee that the email is user@hostname, then how else do you expect to determine what their email is other than asking them?

Comment: maybe it's saved in some config file. I don't know, that's why I asked here. 
Thanks for the answer, but i can't ask the user since the program is a daemon

Comment: Saying that it is in a config file completely changes the question.  Now you've gone from "How do I determine a user's email address based on system characteristics?" to "How do I read a config file?", which answer varies depending on whether you want to manually parse such a file or use an existing library.  Also, do you want to default to a value from a config file and fallback to the environmental value of user@hostname?  Clear questions help get clear answers. :)

Comment: I think he means an existing config file, that happens to contain the email address he can use. But there isn't any such config file.

Comment: NO, i was jsut stating that the email might be stored on a config file that i am not aware of. if you know that config file tell me, and I'll read it. what part of the question wasn't clear?! if you read the question you can see that I know how to get the email by getting the user and hostname and putting them together. I was asking what happens when the email is something else. but as usual in this place people dont' answer the questions, they just asks more questions. my favorite is: Why do you want to do this...? I think i'll stop here since I am getting frustrated.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you were wondering if there already existed a standard config file which would contain that information and you just weren't sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the actual email address in any standard way.  I would try to send the mail to just `username`.  Chanses that it will end up on the correct domain are actually not that bad ...

Answer (score 0):

Check in the terminal you're using, that is  :

> root@peter-laptop#

for **root** users it is shown before the `#` sign, that is

`root@peter-laptop` or `peter@peter-laptop#` for user peter

Answer (score 0):

Try to get to /var/mail/ and there you should have a file for each user that has (not all users have to have it) an email address. And you can indeed read the mail from those files.

Then you can redirect the mail to anywhere else with the sendmail tool.